# Display Random Post in Author Page

Tags: author

By default when we open any author's page, WordPress displays latest posts from that author first.

What I want: If anyone opens any author's page, it will display *random* posts from that author.

I have searched everywhere but I couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this query in themes `functions.php`

```
function ng_author_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_author()
        && $query->is_main_query() ) {
            // your code to set $current_user_name here
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'ng_author_query' );
```

Let me know if you have any problem?

Comment: yes, it works, thank you so much. you made my day :)

Comment: & i have one more question what should i have to do : To display random post, whenever someone opens any Tag page or any Category page

Comment: use same query change only check 
$query->is_tag()
$query->is_category()

Comment: great, it's working, god bless you, thanks one again.